# Import a variable from a function in file1.py to file2.py

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a python file named as `file1.py`, which has the following functions:

```
def randomize_alt(res,start):
    seed=start
    need=''
    while len(need)!=352:
        if seed>=len(res):
            seed=start+1
        need+=res[seed]
        seed+=2
    return need

def generate_keys(user):
    original_hash = keccak.get_hash_of(user.encode('utf-8')) 
    res=original_hash.decode('utf-8')
    print(f"Some Output: {res}")
    want=randomize_alt(res,0)
    print("\nThe alternate bits the output: ",want)
    ind=0;ans=[];tmp=[]
    cnt=0
    keys=[]
    while ind<352:
        string=want[ind:ind+2]
        ind+=2
        tmp.append(int(string,16))
        if ind%8==0:
            ans.append(tmp)
            tmp=[]
            cnt=cnt+1
        if cnt==4:
            keys.append(ans)
            cnt=0
            ans=[]
    return keys
```

Now, I have another file named as `file2.py` with the following content:

```
from file1 import *
from file1 import generate_keys
get_keys = generate_keys("SomeInput")
print(f"\n\nThe generated keys for SomeInput are: {get_keys}")
#get first 32 characters of the string obtained
key = generate_keys("Pars03")
print(len(want))
```

Now, I need to use the `want` variable from `generate_keys` in `file1.py`, in `file2.py`.

I tried out the following thing:

```
from file1 import *
from file1 import generate_keys
```

It gives me the following error:
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'want'`

I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

**EDIT 1**: I declared the want variable as `global` and outside the `generate_keys` function.

Now, the length of `want` in `file1` is coming out to be correct but in `file2`, it comes out to be 0, which means it is treating it as empty string.

Comment: You can't import a local variable of a function into an other module. The `want` variable must be global. Define it in `file1.py` but outside the function `generate_keys`; inside the function `generate_keys` insert the instruction `global want`.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Give me a feedback please.

Comment: @frankfalse I was able to solve it using this. Thank you. :)

Comment: @frankfalse but I am facing yet another issue. The length of ```want``` in file1 is coming out to be correct but in file2, it comes out to be 0, which means it is treating it as empty string. I have updated the question with the change I made to the file.

Comment: you're really jumping through hoops here to retrieve this variable. why can you not simply return it alongside `keys`?

Comment: @AnkushSoni Do you see the answer? Is it useful?

Comment: @frankfalse yes, replied there. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First correction

In `file1.py`

```
want = ""     <---- define want outside of generate_keys()

def generate_keys(user):
    global want      <----- Use global for want
    
    # your code
    ...

    return keys
```

### Second correction

In `file2.py` you have to change the instruction `from file1 import *` and import the module `file1`:

```
#from file1 import *    <---- remove this import
import file1        # <------------ add this import
from file1 import generate_keys

get_keys = generate_keys("SomeInput")
print(f"\n\nThe generated keys for SomeInput are: {get_keys}")
#get first 32 characters of the string obtained
#key = generate_keys("Pars03").want[:32]   <------ THIS IS YOUR wrong code
print(file1.want[:32])  #<----- change want[:32] to file1.want[:32]
```

### Other solution

An other way to solve your problem is leave unchanged the code of `file1.py` but return want with the call of function `generate_keys()`:

```
def randomize_alt(res,start):
    # your code
    ...

def generate_keys(user):
    # your code
    ...
    return keys, want
```

In this case is not necessary to declare `want` outside of `generate_keys()` and you don't need to use the keyword `global`.

`file2.py` becomes as followed:

```
from file1 import generate_keys

get_keys = generate_keys("SomeInput")
print(f"\n\nThe generated keys for SomeInput are: {get_keys}")
#get first 32 characters of the string obtained
key, want = generate_keys("Pars03") # <----- generate_keys() returns key and want
print("want = \'" + want[:32]  + "\'")
```

Comment: For me, the alternative solution that you mentioned worked better. I tried out both but the second one was more efficient and worked well for me. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Good I'm happy and thank you for the accept of the answer